# Can't do loop cut or ring on my mesh

Tags: modeling, loop

My problem is that I can't ring or loop-cut a set of polygons that are co-planar.

[image: No-can-do]

This is the sort of thing that's happening, as you can see I can only affect 2 faces at a time. I've cleaned up the mesh, welded all vert's and made sure there aren't any holes in the mesh in the area that I was to cut a ring/loop.

Comment: Loop cuts will only work on quads. If you have triangles of n-gons, you can't use them.

Comment: Thank you. I was completely unaware that we could only cut quads.  Thank you for your help. :)